# Finding and modifying function definitions (C++) via bash-script

Tags: c++, bash, parsing

Currently I am working on a fairly large project. In order to increase the quality of our code, we decided to enforce the treatement of return values (Error Codes) for every function. GCC supports a warning concerning the return value of a function, however the function definition has to be preceeded by the following flag.

```
static __attribute__((warn_unused_result)) ErrorCode test() { /* code goes here */ }
```

I want to implement a bashscript that parses the entire source code and issues a warning in case the

```
__attribute__((warn_unused_result))
```

is missing. 
Note that all functions that require this kind of modification return a type called ErrorCode.
Do you think this is possible via a bash script ?

Comment: I would recommend that you consider writing this as a clang plugin. I wrote a plugin which analyzes symbol usage and warns about useless includes in about 350 lines of code, so it is not especially difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way I could imagine is via `ctags`. You create a tag file over all your source code, and then parse the tags file. However, I'm not quite sure about the format of the tags file. The variant I'm using here (Exuberant Ctags 5.8) seems to put an "`f`" in the fourth column, if the tag represents a function. So in this case I would use `awk` to filter all tags that represent functions, and then grep to throw away all lines without `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))`.

So, in a nutshell, first you do

```
$ ctags **/*.c
```

This creates a file called "tags" in the current directory. The command might also be `ctags-exuberant`, depending on your variant. The `**/*.c` is a glob pattern that might work in your shell - if it doesn't, you have to supply your source files in another way (look at the `ctags`options).

Then you filter the funktions:

```
$ cat tags | awk -F '\t' '$4 == "f" {print $0}' | grep -v "__attribute__((warn_unused_result))"
```

Comment: I took a look at  this and it appeares to be quite promising. However from what i can tell, the method doesn't care about the kind of return value a function has. However, I only want to treat functions with return value ErrorCode

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that in your question. So, then you will have to play a bit with regular expressions. A first attempt could look like that: `cat tags | awk -F '\t' '$4 == "f" {print $3}' | grep '.*ErrorCode .*('`. Note that I let `awk` only print column `$3`, which contains a pattern for the function in my version of `ctags`. However, I'm not quite sure if this works in special cases, like, when the return type is on a different line than the function name. You should play a bit with it and control the results.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can use `sed` with regular expressions. The following worked for me on a couple of test files I tried:

```
sed -r "s/ErrorCode\s+\w+\s*(.*)\s*\{/__attribute__((warn_unused_result)) \0/g" test.cpp
```

If you're not familiar with regex, the pattern basically translates into:

ErrorCode, some whitespace, some alphanumerics (function name), maybe some whitespace, open parenthesis, anything (arguments), close parenthesis, maybe some whitespace, open curly brace.

If this pattern is found, it is prefixed by `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))`. Note that this only works if you are putting the open curly brace always in the same line as the arguments and you don't have line breaks in your function declarations.

Comment: Thanks! I guess i could use this. However, it might yield many mistakes. From what I got, this will automatically replace the designated occurrences. That's a bit too hardcore for my taste. Are there any options such that the command only returns the line and file where a replacement could possibly take place, such that I can still decide whether to do it or not?

Comment: You can `grep -E "ErrorCode\s+\w+\s*(.*)\s*\{"` to print all the lines that match the regex.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible in the general case. The C++ grammar is the most complex of all the languages I know of, and C++ is not parsable via regular expressions in the general case. You might succeed if you limit yourself to a very narrow set of uses, but I am not sure how feasible it is in your case.
I also do not think the excersise is worth the effort, since sometimes ignoring the result of the function is an OK thing.

Comment: It's not that complex, it's a pretty strict language.

Comment: Well, something can be very strict and very complex at the same time. Like I said before, regexp parsing of a general C++ code is not possible.

Comment: Parsing a file created via ctags worked for me. Also deals with namespaces inline-functions, templates ...